# Is there any ATM at Lima airport (Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM) that doesn't charge any fee?

Tags: airports, fees-and-charges, atms, lima, lim

Is there any ATM at ([Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Ch%C3%A1vez_International_Airport)) that doesn't charge any fee?

I saw many Global Net ATMs at the international terminal (baggage claim area) but they charge a pretty high fee:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think all ATM's in the world will charge a fee, unless it's from your own bank.

Comment: @JuanCa thanks, do you mean any ATM in Peru will charge a fee?

Comment: I used to live in Ecuador (pretty close) and that is true, any ATM will charge you (except from your own bank). I'm guessing Peru will be the same (I've been there long time ago though)

Comment: I don't agree with @JuanCa; There are plenty of ATMs around the world that are not hosted by my bank and which do not charge a fee for withdrawing money from my account in my bank. But, I do find this very much depends on which bank you bank with, and agreements between your bank and other banks.

Comment: @JuanCa some ATMs in Lima eg  Banco de Crédito del Perú doesn't have any fee any in the case the debit/credit card comes from a different bank (at least in some cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

Some ATM's will charge a fee, some will not. Majority will charge a fee for withdrawal. Most banks have a certain "network" or "chain" or ATMs that offer you free access to withdraw money from your bank. If you go outside of this "network", e.g. Overseas ATM, then you will most likely be charged a fee accordingly.

---

#### Long answer:

There are a few different types of ATM fees, all provided by [Bankrate.com - How much are ATM fees](https://www.bankrate.com/banking/how-much-are-atm-fees/):

- **ATM operator fee**. Also known as the surcharge, an operator fee is charged by the ATM owner to noncustomers using its ATMs. ATM owners could be a different bank, a business unrelated to banking or even an individual investor looking to earn passive income.
- **Your bank’s out-of-network fee**. If you use an ATM machine outside of your bank’s network, you may get stuck paying that other bank’s fee — plus your own bank may charge you a fee. Some banks waive out-of-network fees, while others will reimburse you for ATM fees charged by outside banks, usually up to a limit.
- **International transaction fee**. Consumers who use ATMs while traveling outside the U.S. will want to be aware of additional fees. For example, Bank of America customers with the Advantage SafeBalance Banking account in New York who use an outside of BofA’s network are charged $2.50 for each withdrawal, transfer or balance inquiry in the U.S. In addition, the ATM operator may impose an access fee for withdrawals. Other financial institutions charge lower transaction fees: Connexus Credit Union charges up to a 1.5 percent transaction fee, while Fidelity customers with a debit card through a brokerage account pay a 1 percent foreign transaction fee.

There is a [Singapore website](https://www.finder.com/sg/atm-usage-fees-around-the-world) that contains a search engine for which countries offer ATM fees for withdrawal.

> From [TripSavvy - Using ATMs in Peru](https://www.tripsavvy.com/using-atms-in-peru-1619885):
>
> > Most ATMs in Peru do not charge you a transaction fee -- but your bank back home probably does. This charge is often between $5 and $10 for every withdrawal (sometimes more). There might also be an additional 1 to 3 percent transaction fee on all credit and debit card withdrawals abroad.

> From [ATM Travel Guide - Peru](https://www.atmtravelguide.com/atms-in-peru/):
>
> > GlobalNet ATMs and other standalone cash machines tend to be towards the higher end, so be aware of these machines. Your best bet would be to use a Scotiabank bank ATM where possible as there is often no surcharge for international account withdrawals. You will also probably get charged a fee by your own bank